# How to find inside many <div> tags? (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find the content inside the following tag:

```
<h4 id="rfq-info-header-id" class="pr-3 mb-3">
        RFQ1526090
      </h4>
```

[image]

Full code:

```
<rfq-display-header-seller>
   <div class="card-body pb-0">
      <div class="row">
         <div id="rfq-info-header-col-1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="small text-muted">RFQ ID</div>
            <h4 id="rfq-info-header-id" class="pr-3 mb-3">
               RFQ1526090
            </h4>
```

I tried:

```
rfq_id = [tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.find_all(name='h4', attrs={'id': 'rfq-info-header-id','class': 'pr-3 mb-3'})]
print(rfq_id)
```

But this resulted in empty list `[]`.
Is this because the h4 tag is inside many  tags? How to simplify the code to extract the data  inside  tag in the above code

Comment: try either `pr-3` or `mb-3` for the class attr

Comment: Post the HTML code and not an image. Since the element you need has an ```id```, why use ```find_all()``` ? ```id``` should be unique in the document. You can get the element using  ```.find()``` and ```id```.

Comment: Do include the source URL in the post.

Comment: @Ram .find() prints None

Comment: HTMl code posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting output as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc="""

<rfq-display-header-seller>
   <div class="card-body pb-0">
      <div class="row">
         <div id="rfq-info-header-col-1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="small text-muted">RFQ ID</div>
            <h4 id="rfq-info-header-id" class="pr-3 mb-3">
               RFQ1526090
            </h4>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
# rfq_id = soup.find('h4').text
# print(rfq_id)

rfq_id = [t.get_text(strip=True) for t in soup.find_all('h4')]

print(rfq_id)
```

Output:

```
['RFQ1526090']
```

Output using only find method:

```
RFQ1526090
```

Comment: while trying your  code, it returns the answer but when I do it with the webpage, it shows the empty list

Comment: According to your question my answer is producing the correct result. You should  post 
 code along with webpage if possible. You can create new post. Thanks